# Import dragula in angular 5 JIT not working

Tags: angular, dragula

I use dragula in my angular-cli project and need to import the dragula object. In my package.json, I added dragula as a dependency and in my component, I import dragula as follow:

```
import dragula from 'dragula';
```

I then log the object to see if it exists `console.log(dragula)`. Surprisingly when I compile the app in AOT mode, the object exists while when I build it in JIT mode, it doesn't exist! Is it a bug from `dragula` or am I missing something?